# React child component dynamic style

Tags: reactjs

I've created a child component that I'm using all over my App and I want each time to give it a different style. I tried to pass a style prop and change it dynamically but since I'm also using React SCSS module style it's not working. Here is my parent component:

```
import Widget from "../Widget";

const Cost = (props) => {
  const renderPage = () => {
    return (
      <div className={classes.pageContainer}>
        <Widget title={"title"} subTitle={"subTitle"} styleName={"**cost-style-widget**"}/>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return(
    <div className={classes.costDril}>{renderPage()}</div>
   )
}
```

This is the child component:

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Widget.module.scss";

const Widget = ({ title, subTitle, **styleName** }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.staticWid}>
      <div className=**{classes.styleName}**>{title}</div>
      <div>{subTitle}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default StaticSingleWidget;
```

And the child component scss file looks like this:

```
.staticWid {
.cost-style-widget{
    background-color: red;
   }
}
```

How can I implement it so it will dynamically work with scss module?

Thanks

Comment: Just use `props.styleName`

Comment: It's not working since I'm using scss module and the css won't apply if I won't connect it with "classes.name_of_the_wanted_class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `props.styleName` as key-value for `classes`?

```
<div className={classes.staticWid}>
  <div className={classes[props.styleName]}>{title}</div>
  <div>{subTitle}</div>
</div>
```